# Matlab function or Simulink to solve ODE

Tags: simulink

For a large project that uses Simulink, is it better to creating a subsystem within Simulink to solve an ode using the assortment of blocks or use a MATLAB function block inside Simulink that makes a call to the ode solver of your choice. This is more of a coding etiquette question.

Comment: Why not count the cpu cycles each will use then compare.

Comment: good point, thank you